# Why my Ldirectord check multiple times on read server every interval?

Tags: lvs

I have a Ldirectord server and two real servers. My ldirectord used to check the request page on real server once in every interval, but now I found that it check four times. I have monitored the log on both real servers, they have the same problem.

Here is my ldirectord configuration:

> checktimeout=10
>   checkinterval=5
>   autoreload=yes
>   logfile="/var/log/ldirectord.log"
>   quiescent=no
>   virtual=192.168.1.100:80
>
> > ```
> >    fallback=127.0.0.1:80
> >    real=192.168.1.10:80 gate
> >    real=192.168.1.20:80 gate
> >    service=http
> >    request="lb.html"
> >    receive="still alive"
> >    scheduler=sh
> >    persistent=60
> >    protocol=tcp
> >    checktype=negotiate
> > ```

Ldirectord will connect to each real server once every 5 seconds (checkinterval) and request 192.168.0.10:80/test.html (real/request).

The access log in real server:

> 192.168.1.100 - - [13/Jun/2012:10:36:44 -0700] "GET /lb.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "libwww-perl/5.805"
>   192.168.1.100 - - [13/Jun/2012:10:36:44 -0700] "GET /lb.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "libwww-perl/5.805"
>   192.168.1.100 - - [13/Jun/2012:10:36:44 -0700] "GET /lb.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "libwww-perl/5.805"
>   192.168.1.100 - - [13/Jun/2012:10:36:44 -0700] "GET /lb.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "libwww-perl/5.805"
>   192.168.1.100 - - [13/Jun/2012:10:36:49 -0700] "GET /lb.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "libwww-perl/5.805"
>   192.168.1.100 - - [13/Jun/2012:10:36:49 -0700] "GET /lb.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "libwww-perl/5.805"
>   192.168.1.100 - - [13/Jun/2012:10:36:49 -0700] "GET /lb.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "libwww-perl/5.805"
>   192.168.1.100 - - [13/Jun/2012:10:36:49 -0700] "GET /lb.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "libwww-perl/5.805"
>   192.168.1.100 - - [13/Jun/2012:10:36:54 -0700] "GET /lb.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "libwww-perl/5.805"
>   192.168.1.100 - - [13/Jun/2012:10:36:54 -0700] "GET /lb.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "libwww-perl/5.805"
>   192.168.1.100 - - [13/Jun/2012:10:36:54 -0700] "GET /lb.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "libwww-perl/5.805"
>   192.168.1.100 - - [13/Jun/2012:10:36:54 -0700] "GET /lb.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "libwww-perl/5.805"

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can say is that I see the same issue on our deployments.

I believe this is to do with consistency checking, the multiple checks at one time ensuring the response gained is consistent and thus the check passes.

I have not been able to find any documentation mentioning this as something that can be altered.

With all that being said, if the service is working as expected despite the multiple checks taking the old addage "If it aint broke don't fix it" may be adviseable.

If however you absolutely must remove the multiple checks (which if they are run for consistency I would highly advise against doing), then futher research into a configuration variable if it exists would be needed; and editing of the code and recompilation if not.